# Asp.net MVC - Move Areas folder to another folder like MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an existing project built using web forms. Now i want to include `MVC` in same project. But all work related to `MVC` should be placed inside a MVC folder. Is it possible to move \Areas to root\MVC\Areas

Comment: may be , check it , but it will browsing on url base not directly on mvc routing

Answer (score 0):

You should decide on the framework engine first, whether you want **Asp.Net** **Routing** or **MVC** **Routing**. Both of these frameworks have their own way to handle requests and redirect to the function you want to invoke.

Yes you can move your Areas folder, but ensure your **_ViewStart.cshtml** is properly configured to point to the proper _Layout.cshtml

In MVC framework we can continue to use Html Web forms and then tie them to the Actions of your choice.

Although this is not recommended to mix Asp.Net Forms and Asp.Net MVC. Nonetheless it is possible.

Here is an article explaining the same.

https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/asp.net/mixing-web-forms-and-asp.net-mvc/